# How to remove double quotes in variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have this variable:

```
var sup = product[0]; // product[0] is equal to '8876532'
```

I would like to removed the double or single quotes. I tried these 2 options but it didn't work:

```
sup.replace(/"/g, "");
```

and

```
sup.replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Any help with this, would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is an x/y problem, what you have is a string, and you want a number

Comment: `var sup = "asd\"asd'asd"; sup.replace(/["']/g, "");` gives `'asdasdasd'`. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin I think it's just the fact OP didn't take the returned value.

Comment: Wow I am surprised how often this mistake is made, I have seen it at least three times on SO :)

Comment: @dystroy — Quite probably. It would help if they had provided a test case that showed how they were testing the result.

Comment: @Mikey I'm also sure it's a duplicate (hence my no-rep answer). I'm just too lazy to find it...

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for explaining - was wondering why you marked it CW :)

Comment: Another problem with this question is that we don't see if the quotes are part of the string or not...

Comment: @dystroy I agree. I sometimes feel people don't like to share what they are really doing which is ok, but it makes it a lot harder to get a good answer and the people in this community generaly don't like unclear questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sup.replace(/["']/g, "");` is going right way but you're just needing to store in a variable like @destryo has answered.

```
sup = sup.replace(/["']/g, "");
```

But I think you're needing to convert it to a number. If so, you may use parseInt:

```
parseInt(sup, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solution worked for me. I was trying to do this:

if(product[0] !== undefined) {
var sup = product[0].replace(/["']/g, "");
}
sup = parseInt(sup, 10);

if (typeof sup == 'number' && !isNaN(sup)){

// Create a JSON object

}

Answer (score 7):

You have to take the value `replace` returns :

```
sup = sup.replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Comment: That being said, `sup = sup.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');` would remove *anything* that isn't a digit.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Actually, you'd need `sup = sup.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');` to do that.

Comment: @JLRishe Ah yes - you're right. The wonders of switching back and forth between PHP and JS and forgetting that PHP is the only language with a default global modifier.

Comment: A better regex would be `/\D+/g`.

Comment: @dystroy Completely agree that it's better. Is there any *actual* difference in regex compilation between the two, though? Do they internally map to the same functionality, or does the negating regex cause some double-stuff?

Comment: @h2ooooooo PHP isn't the only one. .NET does global matches, but it's a major gotcha in JavaScript.

Comment: Feature-wise, they're exactly the same. I don't know the internals of js regex engines so I don't know if they would lead to differences in the internal representations (I guess not).